# google-assistant-sdk update hotword to pushtotalk

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

On day 28 they put an update that google-assistant-sdk now goes with the command googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk. Previously I went with googlesamples-assistant-hotword. The previous command allowed you to say ok google and I was beginning to hear you. Now you have to give it to enter. Does anyone know how I can do to make it like before I say google google start listening to the assistant?

Comment: You may want to look at a third-party hotword library, such as [Snowboy](https://github.com/Kitt-AI/snowboy).

Answer (score 0):

Install the google service like indicated here:

https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/

Then install then in the venv google library:

```
source env/bin/activate
pip install google-assistant-library
```

Then you can run google assistant with the hotword:

```
googlesamples-assistant-hotword --project-id project --device-model-id model
```